# Sort forms ListView with percentage value

Tags: c#, forms, sorting, listview

I've writen a generic method to sort a listview by clicking on the column header you want to sort. This works rather well with very little code. It also recognises by default numbers and sorts them correctly.
However, I also want to be able to sort percentages, Does anyone have an idea how to best do this? I think it should somehow be able to sort items on character but from right to left.

The code for the generic sorter looks like the following:

```
private void GenericListviewColumnSorter(object sender, ColumnClickEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewColumnSorter listViewSorter = ((ListViewColumnSorter)((ListView)sender).ListViewItemSorter);

    if (listViewSorter == null)
    {
        ((ListView)sender).ListViewItemSorter = new ListViewColumnSorter();
        listViewSorter = ((ListViewColumnSorter)((ListView)sender).ListViewItemSorter);
    }

    listViewSorter.SortColumn = e.Column;

    if (listViewSorter.Order == SortOrder.Ascending) listViewSorter.Order = SortOrder.Descending;
    else listViewSorter.Order = SortOrder.Ascending;

    (sender as ListView).Sort();
}
```

The way the  percentages are sorted by this look like this: 
90% 
60% 
5% 
12% 
100% 
100% 
0%

---

### EDIT

The ListViewColumnSorter class is basically the same as described on [the microsoft support page](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319401/how-to-sort-a-listview-control-by-a-column-in-visual-c).

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Windows.Forms;

/// <summary>
/// This class is an implementation of the 'IComparer' interface.
/// </summary>
public class ListViewColumnSorter : IComparer
{
/// <summary>
/// Specifies the column to be sorted
/// </summary>
private int ColumnToSort;
/// <summary>
/// Specifies the order in which to sort (i.e. 'Ascending').
/// </summary>
private SortOrder OrderOfSort;
/// <summary>
/// Case insensitive comparer object
/// </summary>
private CaseInsensitiveComparer ObjectCompare;

/// <summary>
/// Class constructor.  Initializes various elements
/// </summary>
public ListViewColumnSorter()
{
// Initialize the column to '0'
ColumnToSort = 0;

// Initialize the sort order to 'none'
OrderOfSort = SortOrder.None;

// Initialize the CaseInsensitiveComparer object
ObjectCompare = new CaseInsensitiveComparer();
}

/// <summary>
/// This method is inherited from the IComparer interface.  It compares the two objects passed using a case insensitive comparison.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="x">First object to be compared</param>
/// <param name="y">Second object to be compared</param>
/// <returns>The result of the comparison. "0" if equal, negative if 'x' is less than 'y' and positive if 'x' is greater than 'y'</returns>
public int Compare(object x, object y)
{
int compareResult;
ListViewItem listviewX, listviewY;

// Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
listviewX = (ListViewItem)x;
listviewY = (ListViewItem)y;

// Compare the two items
compareResult = ObjectCompare.Compare(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);

// Calculate correct return value based on object comparison
if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Ascending)
{
// Ascending sort is selected, return normal result of compare operation
return compareResult;
}
else if (OrderOfSort == SortOrder.Descending)
{
// Descending sort is selected, return negative result of compare operation
return (-compareResult);
}
else
{
// Return '0' to indicate they are equal
return 0;
}
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the number of the column to which to apply the sorting operation (Defaults to '0').
/// </summary>
public int SortColumn
{
set
{
ColumnToSort = value;
}
get
{
return ColumnToSort;
}
}

/// <summary>
/// Gets or sets the order of sorting to apply (for example, 'Ascending' or 'Descending').
/// </summary>
public SortOrder Order
{
set
{
OrderOfSort = value;
}
get
{
return OrderOfSort;
}
}

}
```

Comment: What is `ListViewColumnSorter` as its not default for forms

Comment: It's a class example provided by the [microsoft support pages](https://support.microsoft.com/en-us/help/319401/how-to-sort-a-listview-control-by-a-column-in-visual-c) with some minor changes. I've edited my OP.

Comment: In the example they just put it there, it isn't recognized by visual studio for me. Usually if I only need an import it will import it for me. I have `System.Windows.Forms` referenced ~_~

Comment: These are all the references I have for the ListViewColumnSorter class:  using System;
using System.Collections;
using System.Globalization;
using System.Windows.Forms;

Comment: Still nothing, is it an old .Net version?

Comment: Or did you make the class yourself. Because in the example they seem to get it from the default library

Comment: Damn, sorry, didn't copy the full thing off of the Microsoft website. I've updated the OP again. Sorry about that.

Comment: Found the solution, posting it now

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok the problem lies in the comparison, its string based and not int. This is easily fixed however because the `ObjectCompare.Compare` returns -1, 0 or 1 to tell you if its 'less', equal or 'more'. We can easily return these numbers but with our own comparison.

Change this part:

```
int compareResult;
ListViewItem listviewX, listviewY;

// Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
listviewX = (ListViewItem)x;
listviewY = (ListViewItem)y;

// Compare the two items
compareResult = ObjectCompare
                   .Compare
                   (listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text,
                    listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
```

To this:

```
int compareResult = 0;//Give value because if/else
ListViewItem listviewX, listviewY;

// Cast the objects to be compared to ListViewItem objects
listviewX = (ListViewItem)x;
listviewY = (ListViewItem)y;

Regex percentageExpr = new Regex(@"^([1-9]?[0-9]|100)( %|%)");

// Compare the two items
if (percentageExpr.IsMatch(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Tex‌​t) 
 && percentageExpr.IsMatch(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text‌​))
{
    int textY = Convert.ToInt32( listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort]
                                 .Text.Replace( "%", String.Empty ) );
    int textX = Convert.ToInt32( listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort]
                                 .Text.Replace( "%", String.Empty ) );

    compareResult =
    ( textX > textY )
        ? 1
        : textX == textY
                ? 0 : -1;
}
else
{
    compareResult = ObjectCompare
                   .Compare
                   (listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text
                   , listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text);
}
```

Comment: @Ben Good to hear!

Comment: I made a minor change to use regular expression to prevent error's when a different column also contains a % character. Regex percentageExpr = new Regex(@"^([1-9]?[0-9]|100)( %|%)"); and for the if 'if (percentageExpr.IsMatch(listviewY.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text) && percentageExpr.IsMatch(listviewX.SubItems[ColumnToSort].Text))'

Comment: @Ben Changed post, thanks for the update. Helps others with a more robust solution!